# Grouping field doesn't show up in summary report after adding it?

Tags: reporting

I have summary report which is grouped by 'IMP number' but even after adding it to the report, it is not seen on the report nor the records. What could be three problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you positive your filters are not set in a way that might exclude records which include the data? "All <objectname" and "All Time" in the top portion of the filters view when customizing the report.

Answer (score 0):

If your report type is custom then you should select the IMP number to be shown in the report. While report creation all the fields which you wanted to shown on report should be selected to the right from left.